# How to get all child threads from a thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working on a framework that allows customer write their own code in java. And this framework calls their code in a thread (let say thread A) to do customized things.

But customer may create new threads in their code. So problem is how to know all customer code's thread finished? Or how to forbid customer create thread in their code?

Thanks.

Comment: Allowing client code to create threads would be a havoc IMO. Why do they need threads for? Performance? Well, in that case, performance consideration should be taken care by your base framework which should know how to handle time-consuming requests. There is a lot of frameworks out there which allow clients to write custom scripts but I think it is done in a controlled environment (i.e. client can't bring down the JVM by calling `System.exit(1)` etc.). I think RMI provides for something similar wherein clients can submit custom requests. Does RMI fit your bill?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new [ThreadGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html) for the client code. The `activeCount` method tells you how many client threads are active in a given moment, and the `enumerate` method allows you to enumerate the threads. To wait for the termination of the entire group you can enumerate the threads and call `join` on each one.

If you want to disallow the creation of new threads, I believe you can achieve that with a custom `SecurityManager`, but I don't know the details.

Comment: But how Framework knows the number of threads customer created? May be framework can provide a method to create threads, A method takes a runnable as a parameter and keep count while starting the thread.

Comment: @TitoGeorge You want to know the total number of threads created, including threads that have finished running? I doubt that's possible unless the users of the framework co-operate.

Comment: I agree. Like SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable doRun) Framework should provide one. But useful only if the users of the framework understands the importance of using it.